# Changing main font in documents changes weight in monospaced family

Tags: overleaf, algorithmic

I'm using *times* package for my main font in the document. However, it changes the weight of the monospaced font in the *algorithmic* environment. I want the monospaced font to be displayed as if I didn't use the *times* package. How can I achieve that?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm}
\usepackage{times}
\makeatletter
\algrenewcommand\ALG@beginalgorithmic{\ttfamily}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclidâ€™s algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[3]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of $a$ and $b$}
      \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \While{$r \not= 0$}\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is 0}
        \State $a \gets b$
        \State $b \gets r$
        \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is $b$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: times package is really obsolete, for a modern times clone use `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should *never* do `\usepackage{times}`, especially if your document has math formulas: you get a horrible mixture of Times for text and Computer Modern for math and the two fonts do not go along, because the shapes of the letters are too different.

You can use `mathptmx` instead. If you don't want Courier as the monospaced font (and I'd agree with you), you can reinstate the standard Computer Modern Mono (such a mixture is not bad).

Don't forget `\frenchspacing` (check the space after `g.c.d.` if you leave it out). And the 0 at the end of line 3 should be `$0$`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode,algorithm}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtt} % Computer Modern Mono

\makeatletter
\algrenewcommand\ALG@beginalgorithmic{\ttfamily\frenchspacing}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{Euclid's algorithm}\label{euclid}
  \begin{algorithmic}[3]
    \Procedure{Euclid}{$a,b$}\Comment{The g.c.d. of $a$ and $b$}
      \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \While{$r \not= 0$}\Comment{We have the answer if $r$ is 0}
        \State $a \gets b$
        \State $b \gets r$
        \State $r \gets a \bmod b$
      \EndWhile\label{euclidendwhile}
      \State \textbf{return} $b$\Comment{The gcd is $b$}
    \EndProcedure
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Compare with `times` instead of `mathptmx`

[image]

However, nowadays you should do `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` instead of `\usepackage{mathptmx}`. I'd keep the `\ttdefault` line anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `times` package changes not just the main font but also the sans serif (to Helvetica) and typewriter (to Courier) fonts. Rather than using `\usepackage{times}`, you can instead just write:

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
```

in place of `\usepackage{times}` to only change the roman font to Times (although note that this does *not* change math typesetting).